# C# - How to Bypass Error cs0212 Cheaply for Programmers and Computers?

Tags: c#, pointers

I want to process many integers in a class, so I listed them into an `int*` array.

```
int*[] pp = new int*[]{&aaa,&bbb,&ccc};
```

However, the compiler declined the code above with the following EXCUSE:

[> You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29ak9b70(VS.90).aspx)

I know I can change the code above to avoid this error; however, we need to consider `ddd` and `eee` will join the array in the future.

```
public enum E {
    aaa,
    bbb,
    ccc,
    _count
}

for(int i=0;i<(int)E._count;i++)

gg[(int)E.bbb]
```

```
Dictionary<string,int>ppp=new Dictionary<string,int>();
ppp["aaa"]=ppp.Count;
ppp["bbb"]=ppp.Count;
ppp["ccc"]=ppp.Count;

gg[ppp["bbb"]]
```

These solution works, but they make the code and the execution time longer.

I also expect a nonofficial patch to the compiler or a new nonofficial C# compiler, but I have not seen an available download for many years; it seems very difficult to have one for us.

Are there better ways so that

1. I do not need to count the count of the array `ppp`.
2. If the code becomes long, there are only several letters longer.
3. The execution time does not increase much.
4. To add `ddd` and `eee` into the array, there are only one or two
   setences for each new member.

Comment: why on earth aren't you using an IEnumerable - List<int> or so on? Why do you think pointers are easier to maintain than a list?

Comment: 1) It's not an "excuse". You cannot "ban" the error because you cannot pass around references to unpinned objects (they can be moved around the memory at any time by the collector). 2) Also, are you sure that "changing this code will make it more difficult to maintain"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In short: you can't change the language rules yourself. You can suppress warnings, but not errors.

Comment: Naughty compiler.  How dare it make excuses about your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET runtime is a managed execution runtime which (among other things) provides [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx). .NET garbage collector (GC)
not only manages the allocation and release of memory, but also transparently moves the objects around the "managed heap", blocking
the rest of your code while doing it.
It also compacts (defragments) the memory by moving longer lived objects together, and even "promoting" them into different parts of the heap, called *generations*, to avoid checking their status too often.

There is a bunch of memory being copied all the time without your program even realizing it. Since garbage collection is an operation that can happen at any time during the execution of your program, any pointer-related 
("unsafe") operations must be done within a small scope, by telling the runtime to "pin" the objects using the `fixed` keyword. This prevents the GC from moving them, but only for a while.

Using pointers and `unsafe` code in C# is not only less safe, but also not very idiomatic for managed languages in general. If coming from a C background, you may feel like at home with these constructs, but C# has a completely different philosophy: your job as a C# programmer should be to write reliable, readable and maintenable code, and only then think about squeezing a couple of CPU cycles for performance reasons. You can use pointers from time to time in small functions, doing some very specific, time-critical code. But even then it is your duty to [profile **before** making such optimizations](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProfileBeforeOptimizing). Even the most experienced programmers often fail at predicting bottlenecks before profiling.

Finally, regarding your actual code:

1. I don't see why you think this:

   ```
   int*[] pp = new int*[] {&aaa, &bbb, &ccc};
   ```

   would be any more performant than this:

   ```
   int[] pp = new int[] {aaa, bbb, ccc};
   ```

   On a 32-bit machine, an `int` and a pointer are of the same size. On a 64-bit machine, a pointer is even bigger.
2. Consider replacing these plain `int`s with a `class` of your own which will provide some context and additional functionality/data to each of these values. Create a new question describing the actual problem you are trying to solve (you can also use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for such questions) and you will benefit from much better suggestions.